# MySQL: How to use variable value from current select statement?

Tags: mysql

I am doing some heavy calculation in MySQL 5.7 where I try to reuse calculated values within a statement in order to save computing power.

Now the following minimal example does a calculation with the result saved in variable @my. The value of the variable is the basis for another calculation:

```
SELECT
    @my :=   SUM (test) as something,
    @my / 10 AS Output
```

This results in the effect that every time I execute it, it will use the @my value from the last execution - the previous select, not the current one.

How can the variable be reset on each statement or is there a better notation that uses the caluclation from the current execution?

Answer (score 0):

you can easy init your variables in a JOIN like this:

SELECT
field1,
@my := field2 * 10,
....
FROM yourTable
JOIN ( SELECT @my := 0 , @other := 99 ) AS INIT;